# How can I cross long gaps?

Tags: nintendo-ds, scribblenauts

In Scribblenauts, what techniques can I use get across long gaps such as pits or lava?  I can't seem to get any bridges that are long enough to solve some levels.

Comment: Pole vault? (Disclaimer: I haven't played this game!)

Comment: Time machines and dinosaurs solve every problem in Scribblenauts.
http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showpost.php?p=16184727

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about flight?
The following items will give Maxwell the ability to fly:

- Wings
- Jetpack
- Magic Carpet
- Flying Broom
- Backpack Helicopter
- Winged Shoes
- NeoGAF

Disclaimer: I've not played the game, but flying sounds like a winning formula for gaps

Source: [Scribblenauts Wiki](http://scribblenauts.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_Fly)

Comment: In the first Scibblenauts, some of these only give you limited flight time; you're often better off with a flying mount like a pegasus or pterodactyl (or helicopter or UFO but that stuff is big).  In Super Scribblenauts I think all flight is unlimited, though.

Answer (score 4):

You might try some flight items, like *Wings, Jetpack, Winged Shoes* or a flying mount such as *Pegasus*, or a *Pterodactyl*.

You could also try attaching a number of *balloons* or *kites* to Maxwell, and then just jumping over the gap; you will be able to jump much farther with enough of either attached.

Alternatively, you can also create a bunch of building materials and attach them together with *glue* or *tape*;  *Flagpoles* work quite well for this.

There's also an item I THINK called *plains* which is basically just low, long grassy hill, that will just stretch across gaps that everything else won't quite reach.  You could try that as well.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the various flight techniques (Wings, Jetpack, etc.), the longest bridge I've been able to create in Scribblenauts is by using "Drawbridge".